# PyQt lineEdit with colors

Tags: pyqt4, text-formatting

I'm trying to format a Qt lineEdit text with colors.

```
 def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText("here be colors")
```

I searched a lot but only found customized drawing widgets with monstrous amounts of code. Is there any easier way to format the lineEdit box than customizing the whole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use a QTextEdit, and limit it to one line.